# iOS devices with 120 Hz - what is the UIKit refresh rate

Tags: ios, performance, uikit, rendering, refresh

In most tutorials or recommendations a value of 60 fps is listed as the ultimate refresh rate for the app to aim for. I.e. if the app is able to consistently provide the user experience at 60 fps there is no more room for improvement.

However, what is the case for the newer devices, e.g. iPad Pro which have 120 Hz refresh rate? Do they actually redraw UI components 120 times per second, meaning that the time to successfully prepare a frame has went down from about 16 ms to 8 ms?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the new devices have a maximum fps of 120 but the default is still 60. If you want to use a 120 fps you need to change the fps value.

This link might give you more informations:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2460/_index.html

I hope this will help.

Comment: It's work, i have this issue on flutter. My app is lock on 60fps.
Thank you